# Embed Java Applet on GitHub Page

Tags: java, github, applet, embed, script-tag

I am working on a Java project that I am hosting on GitHub. I wanted to use GitHub Pages to have a page hosted on GitHub with the applet embedded. Now, I'm trying to embed an applet into the page, with the applet files hosted on GitHub on the `gh-pages` branch. I exported the Java applet as "exploded", so all of the class files show up in their correct hierarchy. In `index.html, I'm using this code:

```
<section id="main_content">
            <script>
                var attributes = {codebase: 'cubesorter/me/nrubin29/cubesorter/',
                    code: 'Viewer.class',
                    archive: 'cubesorter.jar',
                    width: '800',
                    height: '600'};
                var parameters = {java_arguments: '-Xmx256m'}; // customize per your needs
                var version = '1.5'; // JDK version
                deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
            </script>
        </section>
```

However, I get a `ClassNotFoundException` for `Viewer.class`. Do I have everything set up correctly?

Comment: What is the URL of the page?

Comment: I actually deleted the `gh-pages` branch from my repository because I gave up and decided to use a server I already owned. I can set up a repo to continue testing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave comments yet, but I'm wondering if the `ClassNotFoundException` is referring to one of your classes that you wrote or a class from a dependency. Are you depending on external .jar files? They might be on your development environment but not in deployment. Perhaps you need something like Maven to make sure everything (including all the classes) is being deployed.

Comment: I don't have any external libraries. The code is on GitHub if you look in the correct branch: https://github.com/nrubin29/cubesorter/

Comment: I just added to the question that the `CNFE` is for `Viewer.class`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move viewer.class into the cubesorter/tree/gh-pages directory.
Simple fix. Not much more to it.

```
 <!-- try the applet tag instead -->
 <applet src="cubesorter.jar" code="https://github.com/nrubin29/cubesorter/blob/gh-pages/cubesorter/me/nrubin29/cubesorter/Viewer.class?raw=true">Java not supported</applet>

 <!-- <section id="main_content">
        <script>
            var attributes = {codebase: 'cubesorter/me/nrubin29/cubesorter/',
                //How is this even parsed?
                code: 'https:\/\/github.com\/nrubin29\/cubesorte\r/blob/gh-pages/\cubesorter\/me\/nrubin29\/cubesorter\/Viewer.class?raw=true',
                archive: 'cubesorter.jar',
                width: '800',
                height: '600'};
            var parameters = {java_arguments: '-Xmx256m'}; // customize per your needs
            var version = '1.5'; // JDK version
            deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
        </script>
 </section> -->
```

In the code above, I hotlinked viewer.class for you

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean. I am specifying the path to the class file, so that shouldn't matter.

Comment: @nrubin29 - This is not server side: that is the path on the server. You need the path on the client side, like, http://cubesorter.github.io/viewer.class not /nrubin29/cubesorter/gh-pages/viewer.class

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: https:..github.com.nrubin29.cubesorter.blob.gh-pages.cubesorter.me.nrubin29.cubesorter.Viewer.class?raw=true`. Did I forget to escape the `/`s?

Comment: Doubling the `/`s didn't help. I think it's replacing all `/`s with `.`s in the path.

Comment: Using the latest code with the `\/`s, I still get: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: https:..github.com.nrubin29.cubesorte.blob.gh-pages.cubesorter.me.nrubin29.cubesorter.Viewer.class?raw=true`. Note that I am using IntelliJ and testing this locally at http://localhost:63342/CubeSorter%20Web/index.html. Is that the issue?

Comment: Better code: `<applet src="cubesorter.jar" code="https://github.com/nrubin29/cubesorter/blob/gh-pages/cubesorter/me/nrubin29/cubesorter/Viewer.class?raw=true">Java not supported</applet>`

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: https:..github.com.nrubin29.cubesorter.blob.gh-pages.cubesorter.me.nrubin2‌​9.cubesorter.Viewer.class?raw=true`. Also, the `applet` tag is deprecated.

Comment: I know <applet> is deprecated. Try leaving out the code="Viewer.class"

Comment: With `<applet src="cubesorter.jar">Java not supported</applet>`, it doesn't load anything at all.

Comment: I've had this problem before. Try access the webpage from file:///path/to/index.html and add the code="Viewer.class" back

Comment: Didn't help. When I tried dragging the index.html into Safari, I got Java not supported.

Comment: `<applet archive="cubesorter.jar" code="https://github.com/nrubin29/cubesorter/blob/gh-pages/cubesorter/me/nrubin29/cubesorter/Viewer.class?raw=true">Java not supported</applet>` should work. I accidentally put src instead of archive

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: https:..github.com.nrubin29.cubesorter.blob.gh-pages.cubesorter.me.nrubin2‌​9.cubesorter.Viewer.class?raw=true`

Comment: Do you have any idea why it is replacing / with a .

Comment: It might have to do with the fact that Java uses `.`s in its package names and it's interpreting that given path as a package.

Comment: What package name are you using for cubesorter? What you would use with import

Comment: `me.nrubin29.cubesorter.Viewer` is the path to the Viewer class. This is inside of the `src` folder.

Comment: then replace code="Viewer.class" with code="me.nrubin29.cubesorter.Viewer"

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.nrubin2‌​9.cubesorter.Viewer`

Comment: I might just get a Droplet from DigitalOcean and host everything over there. I need a database anyways.

Comment: if you have a codebase attribute, remove it. It causes relative path problems.

Comment: I'm using `<applet archive="cubesorter.jar" code="me.nrubin2‌​9.cubesorter.Viewer">Java not supported</applet>`

Comment: Better code: <applet src="cubesorter.jar" code=https://github.com/nrubin29/cubesorter/blob/gh-pages/cubesorter/me/nrubin2‌​9/cubesorter/Viewer.class?raw=true>Java not supported</applet> –  try without quotes. Someone said that works

Comment: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: github.com.nrubin29.cubesorter.blob.gh-pages.cubesorter.me.…‌‌​​9.cubesorter.Viewer.class?raw=true`

Comment: I need to go for now. I will do more research tomorrow.