# Can an embedded Java Applet be hosted on Git-Pages?

Tags: java, github, applet, markdown, github-pages

I want to embed a java applet (stored in a git repository) in the accompanying github-pages page. Is this possible?

Comment: GitHub pages allows you to serve any files you want.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23281598/6309 could help

Comment: @SLaks Not server side files

Comment: @KrishMunot: I said "serve any file".  Server-side code is executed, not served.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Although GitHub pages can be generated through a simple markdown interface, any files in your branch will be served as part of your gh-pages-site.

This means you can host client side scripts like Java-Applets or JS on your GitHub Pages site.

To host a java applet:

1. [Create a jar file for your Applet.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24628402/the-simplest-way-to-create-jar-file)
2. Place the .jar file into the root of your gh-pages branch.
3. Embed the applet in one of your html pages using your prefered method [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985754/how-to-deploy-a-java-applet-for-todays-browsers-applet-embed-object), or maybe this:

   ```
   *Assuming foo.jar and Bar.class are your file and applet-class*
   <embed 
   id="SomeName"
   type="application/x-java-applet;version=1.6"
   width="999" height="999" 
   archive="foo.jar"
   code="Bar.class"
   pluginspage="http://java.com/download/"
   myParam="YourParams" />
   ```
4. Commit/Push the changes and wait (sometimes gh-pages are not updated immediately).