# Embed .jar files in Github.io

Tags: java, html, github

I am not familiar with HTML/Git, but my java project has 2 files, a driver and the class. I only run the driver. In Eclipse, I exported my project into .jar files. How do I upload that .jar file to Github.io such that when I open the GitHub page it runs the .jar file on the site?

I tried embedding the code as an HTML page, but that didn't work. In all my attempts in that, I used applet> but that didn't work.

Any Idea on how to run .jar files on GitHub.io?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean but open this link:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/24719538/8715880

Comment: Thank you, but I did see that and it didn't work for me